# Reshaping polygon on curve shape on road in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

In ArcMap Editing Tool -> which is End Point Arc Segment. I need similar kind of tool in QGIS.

[image: In ArcMap editing tool is end point arc segment]

[image: I need reshape this polygon as like smooth curve on other side in QGIS]

Comment: Is this a display-issue, or do you need to change the actual geometry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Reshape` tool in the `Advanced Digitizing toolbar`. Right-click the toolbar and select `Advanced Digitizing toolbar`. Using [Reshape tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#reshape-features), you can define the curve you like of the polygon, and it will be adjusted based on the curve you have defined.

[image]

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: I can't see here how to define the curve or arc to edit a polygon.